# HttpAddUrlToUrlGroup failing when run in normal user privilege

Tags: windows, http, webserver, httpserver, winhttp

I am trying to create a server application using HTTP Server API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/http/http-server-api-overview). I am unable to run the application with regular user privilege.

From the command prompt in administrator mode I have reserved the URL ACL

C:> netsh http add urlacl url=https://+:56565/tuhin/ user=\Everyone

Output of show urlacl is as below, which show the entry has got persisted
C:>netsh http show urlacl

```
Reserved URL            : https://+:56565/tuhin/
    User: \Everyone
        Listen: Yes
        Delegate: No
        SDDL: D:(A;;GX;;;WD)
```

When I am running a application in the normal user privilege the HttpAddUrlToUrlGroup is failing with ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED. I am trying to add the URL https://192.168.1.7:56565/tuhin/tuhin2/
192.168.1.7 is one of the active address in my machine.

Please suggest what I am doing wrong.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake. The `HttpAddUrlToUrlGroup` also need to be called with the same prefix used during the reservation. Passing  `https://+:56565/tuhin/tuhin2/` to `HttpAddUrlToUrlGroup` gets accepted when used in an application with normal privileges.